# Interpretation von Kurrent Handschrift

Tags: handwriting, kurrent, interpretation

Interpretation von Kurrent Handschrift

Ich versuche, ein altes Kurrentmanuskript von 1857 von Marcus Jacob Monrad https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Jacob_Monrad an Karl Rosenkranz https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Rosenkranz zu transkribieren.
Weiß jemand, wie man entschlüsseln/interpretieren kann, was XXX im unten stehenden Text sein soll?

*Soweit ich aus Auszügen in der Augsburger A[llgemeine]. Z[eitung]. abnehmen kann, ist die
Haymsche Schrift ein Versuch, den XXX Hegel aus zufälligen Zeitgeistbruchstücken pragmatisch
zusammenzustoppeln, ein Versuch, der wohl sein Interesse haben mag.*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> ... ein Versuch, den **ganzen** Hegel aus zufälligen ...

Gemeint ist vermutlich ein Buch von Hegel oder möglicherweise sogar sein ganzes Werk.

Comment: +1. „ein Buch ... sein ganzes Werk“ bzw. treffender: sein gesamtes *System*. Die (gezwungene, bis zur letzten Konsequenz geführte) Systematizität ist nicht nur das auffallendste äußere Merkmal von H.s Philosophie, sondern zugleich eine seiner Kernaussagen. Und weiter unten wiederholt Monrad: „wahr, dass das Hegelsche *System* gewiß kein subjektiver Einfall, sondern ein Resultat des wahren Zeitgeistes ist“.